# why is the lower integral := sup(L(f,P))?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Im having a hard time visualizing why they are taking the sup(L(f,P)).

to me the lower sum is adding up all the rectangles like we did in calculus but I don't understand why sup would even make sense here. isn't the lower sum already a number, so why would we want to take the sup of one number.

Comment: This is really an abuse of notation.The supremum is meant to be taken over the all partitions $P$

Comment: The lower sum depends on the choice of partition $P$. Since we're approximating $f$ from below, we want to look at the largest number obtainable by a sum of the form $L(f,P)$, and this is the supremum.

Comment: sorry if this seems dumb, but does that mean it just is basically lim as ||P||-> 0 of  L(f,P)?

Comment: @artificialHearts Absolutely

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the lower integral is by definition
$$
\sup \{ L(f,P) \mid P\ \text{is a partition of the underlying interval}\}.
$$
I believe that, after the string $\sup L(f,P)$ of symbols there should be a complementary sentence such as "where the supremum extends over all partitions $P$ of the underlying interval".